# Comparing the results from a database to see if they're the same

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I'm trying to find out how I'd go about comparing 5 sets of results to see if they haven't been selected before in the database, currently I'm selecting 5 random locations and then writing it to a database now what I need to do is compare the results currently being echoed are not the same as previously displayed in the last 5 days

```
// Insert $ouput in to the Database
  $sql5 = "INSERT INTO Already_Selected (AL_S)
  VALUES ('$text4'), ('$text3'), ('$text2'), ('$text1'), ('$text')";
  if ($conn->query($sql5) === TRUE) {
      echo "";
  } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql5 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
```

This is how I'm inserting the locations in to the database.

If anyone can guide me in some way of doing this id be most appreciative. I am new to php

Comment: so pull all the locations already used and compare to see if they have already been used. If you add what your database tables look like it will help as well.

Comment: `Already_Selected`has two columns `AL_S and TS`, `TS = Time Stamp`. `channels` contains one Column `Channel_Locations` how would i compare it though that's what i'm not sure on

Comment: So here is what i would do, add a column at the beginning of `Channel_Location` named `id`,int,255,autoincrement. Then inside of `Already_Selected` table make a new column again with something more unique of an identifier. Maybe something like `cl_id` then you can store the id and check that against other id's in different tables.

Comment: `  #Comparison SQL
 $comp = "SELECT Already_Selected FROM AL_S"; 
 $compare = mysqli_query($conn, $comp);
 $unique = mysqli_query($conn, $sql, $sql1, $sql2, $sql3, $sql4);
 if ($uni == $compare) {
  mysqli_query($conn, $unique);
 } else {

 };
  `

Comment: I think you might be trying to overthink it a little lol. let me add to my answer below a demo for you too see the simple way i compare. Dump the 2 table structure so i can import it and give you an accurate code layout.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer I could give without more example of your code and db tables is:

Table 1 - Locations

Table 2 - Already_Selected

hopefully in table 1 you have some kind of unique identifier to identify each row. I typically just use an id W/ auto increment.

then you can check that id in table 2 and if it matches skip it else use it.

Comment: I've added the layout to my tables in the comment above yours? ^.^